# Changing the value of a DependencyProperty inside its PropertyChangedCallback doesn't update the binding source

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, dependency-properties

I have some C# code of the following form:

```
class FooBehavior : Behavior<Foo>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooPropProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FooProp", typeof(string), typeof(FooBehavior),
                                                                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(FooPropProperty_Changed)
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                                                                                            DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                                                                                        });

    public String FooProp { get { return (string)GetValue(FooPropProperty); } set { SetValue(FooPropProperty, value); } }

    private static void FooPropProperty_Changed(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        /* re-entrancy check done here*/
        // ...

        if (/* args.NewValue is something bad that I can't use */)
            FooProp = (string)args.OldValue;

        try
        {
            /* do stuff here that might throw */
        }
        catch
        {
            FooProp = /* some known good value */;
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I've taken out most of the actual code, but this shows the basics. What is happening is that I have a DependencyProperty where I want to to do validation on the property change, but I can't do it via the normal ValidateValueCallback method. I'd like to set the DependencyProperty back to its original value or to a known good value and have that change propagate to the viewmodel property to which the DependencyProperty is bound.

The problem I have is that when I get a value that I can't use, I can change the DependencyProperty's value, but the viewmodel doesn't see this new value. How can I get the value to propagate back to the viewmodel?

Comment: Have you tried using [`CoerceValueCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback(v=vs.110).aspx) or `PropertyMetadata` instead?

Comment: I tried a `CoerceValueCallback` and it didn't help. The viewmodel property is not updated to the return value of the callback. +1 for the suggestion, though.